# Join where only most similar matching row is joined

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have two tables T0, T1

T0 has two relevant columns T1id and Quantity

T1 has two relevant columns id and Quantity

T1 can have multiple rows with the same id

I want to JOIN based on two conditions:

1. T0.T1id = T1.id
2. T1 row with T1.Quantity that most closely matches T0.Quantity from the set of T0.T1id = T1.id

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Edit: Added example data

```
+----+------+----------+
| T0 | T1id | Quantity |
+----+------+----------+
|  0 |  180 |      112 |
+----+------+----------+

+----+-----+----------+
| T1 | id  | Quantity |
+----+-----+----------+
|  0 | 180 |       50 |
|  1 | 180 |      100 |
|  2 | 180 |      150 |
+----+-----+----------+

+--------+------+----------+------------+
| Result | T1id | Quantity | T1Quantity |
+--------+------+----------+------------+
|      0 |  180 |      112 |        100 |
+--------+------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.T1id, T0.Quantity, 
       FIRST_VALUE(T1.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY T0.T1id ORDER BY ABS(T0.Quantity - T1.Quantity)) T1Quantity
FROM T0 INNER JOIN T1
ON T0.T1id = T1.Id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d0ddea5df2861234196fcb7ba4bc2f0).

Answer (score 0):

You could just do the join, then handle the minimum difference separately.

What if they are equidistant (90 vs. 100) (110 vs. 100). Which is the closest match in that case?

```
SELECT SUB.id,
       SUB.T1id,
       SUB.quantity,
       SUB.T1_quantity
  FROM (SELECT T0.id,
               T1.T1id,
               T0.quantity,
               T1.quantity AS T1_quantity,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T1.id
                                       ORDER BY ABS(T0.quantity - T1.quantity) AS
                                 ) rn_quantity_diff
          FROM T0
         INNER
          JOIN T1
            ON T0.T1id = T1.id
       ) SUB
 WHERE rn_quantity_diff = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Row_number by abs

```
select * 
from (
    select t0.T1id, t0.Quantity, t1.Quantity as t1Quantity,
       row_number() over(partition by t0.T1id order by abs(t0.Quantity - t1.Quantity)) rn
    from t0
    join t1 on t0.T1id = t1.id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t0.*,
       (select t1.quantity
        from t1
        where t1.id = t0.t1id and t1.quantity <= t0.quantity
        order by t1.quantity desc
        limit 1
       ) as t1_quantity
from t0;
```